# How can I make Qt recognize a sequence of keys?

Tags: c++, qt

In my current application, I need to make QT close a window by pressing Shift + Eesc or by pressing Esc 3x.
First, I tried Shift + Esc, it went this way

```
if ((event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape) && (event->key() == Qt::Key_Shift))
  {
    cout << "test" << endl;
    on_close_x_button_clicked();
  }
```

But for some reason, it just doesn't work. I googled it and found something about a `QKeySequence` but I didn't find any example of how to do it properly. I tried some ways with no success like:

```
if ((event->key() == Qt::QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Escape + Qt::Key_Shift)))
  {
      cout << "teste" << endl;
    on_close_x_button_clicked();
  }
}
```

But again, no dice. Can someone point me how to proper implement this functionality?

I also could not find anything that allowed me to create an event based on pressing Escape key 3x. Can someone, please, also teach me how to do it?

I also tried using Shortcuts, and it went like this:

```
    LinAdvancedTestWidget::LinAdvancedTestWidget(QWidget *parent,
                                                 QObject *event_filter,
                                                 SystemEvent *event, int dpi)
        : AdvancedTestWidget(parent, event_filter, event) {
      (void)dpi;
        KeyShiftEsc = new QShortcut(this);
        KeyShiftEsc->setKey(Qt::Key_Shift + Qt::Key_Escape);
        connect(KeyShiftEsc, SIGNAL(activated()), this, SLOT(slotShortcutShiftEsc()));
    }

void LinAdvancedTestWidget::slotShortcutShiftEsc()
{
    cout << "Escape LinAdvancedTestWidget" << endl;
  on_close_x_button_clicked();
}
```

But it again, also does not work :/

Comment: Maybe you want QShortcut: [https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.15/qshortcut.html](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.15/qshortcut.html)

Comment: @drescherjm, thans for your answer! I tried and updated it to my question, still does not work. And btw, how can I make the application close after pressing the Escape key 3x?

Answer (score 1):

Shift is a modifier, not a key, as you seem to compare. You would need to write something like this:

```
if ((event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape) && (event->modifiers() & Qt::Key_Shift))
{
    ...
}
```

Also, it is better if you use the [QWidget::addAction(...)](https://if%20((event-%3Ekey()%20==%20Qt::Key_Escape)%20&&%20(event-%3Ekey()%20==%20Qt::Key_Shift))%20%20%20%7B) method as:

```
QAction *action = new QAction("my action", "Shift+Esc");
myWidget->addAction(action);
```

You can also set [multiple shortcuts](https://if%20((event-%3Ekey()%20==%20Qt::Key_Escape)%20&&%20(event-%3Ekey()%20==%20Qt::Key_Shift))%20%20%20%7B) on an action:

```
action->setShorcuts({"Shift+Esc", QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Esc, Qt::Key_Esc, Qt::Key_Esc)});
```

Comment: thank you very much! The first option worked! But how could I implement it using the event of pressing Escape 3x?

Comment: @MustSee: you cannot. `QKeyEvent` represents a key combination, not key sequence. It is basically a key press, rather than a sequence of key presses. This is also why I mentioned the second approach. You would need to use that. It is in any case a better approach than through `QKeyEvent`. Do not forget to connect your QAction* that way to a slot that runs when the &QAction::triggered signal is emitted.

Comment: if it is not possible to do it using QKeyEvent, is it possible to do it any other way?  I have heard of applications that use a sequence of keys like 3x Escape

Comment: I have just answered that in my previous comment. I gave an example for this in my answer, too. I have a typo in there - it should be `Qt::Key_Escape`, but otherwise should work. Let me know if it does not.